# Log4J - determine if logger cannot write to file system

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to use Log4J in my application, but my problem is that the machine where I want to run this app has not given me write permissions to the local drive. But Log4J is not throwing any errors, it simply skips the logging.

So what I want to do is write some code in which if Log4J cannot write to the local file system it will return some feedback/message in my app. Is there a way to tell if Log4J can write to the local filesystem, from Log4J itself? Or is there any way that I determine how many words Log4J has written into its log file in each operation? It's so then I could determine whether or not logging was actually occurring and then take appropriate action.

Answer (score 2):

have you read the [FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html)

Quote from the site

> No. log4j is not reliable. It is a best-effort fail-stop logging
>   system.
>
> By fail-stop, we mean that log4j will not throw unexpected exceptions
>   at run-time potentially causing your application to crash. If for any
>   reason, log4j throws an uncaught exception, please send an email to
>   the log4j-user@logging.apache.org mailing list. Uncaught exceptions
>   are handled as serious bugs requiring immediate attention.

I prefer my application continue even if logging fails.

What you described is possibly a function of 'application monitoring'. There are many tools to see if particular file system is getting full or a directory/file  not changed for a while etc.

Having said that, you can do basic checks at the very beginning of application - like permissions to create file in the  directory meant for logging.

Comment: And if you read further... "However, log4j will output a single message to System.err indicating that logging can not be performed."

Comment: thanks for the response. my point is whether there is any way so i can get this information that logging can not be performed. if there is any, then please suggest me some.
@jahroy so can i get that message which log4j is sending to System.err! it may sound silly question, but i dont know how to get values from System.err ... thanks!!